# Maps has stopped working since the last update

Tags: google-maps

the map stopped working so For the purpose of development I can no longer access the locations in the map where I changed my password gmail

http://4us.pythonanywhere.com/For-Sale-Listings/city/homes

```
  <div id="map" style="height:400px"></div>
```

```
  <script>
    function initMap(){
      // Map options
      var options = {
        zoom:8,
        center:{lat:42.3601,lng:-71.0589}
      }

      // New map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

      // Listen for click on map
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        alert(event.latLng);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwxfea8ecYMmGKMO39JF1ko5bhF4UocpM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must to enable a billing account for to use google maps